# Nodejs how to access Callback results outsite without setTimeouts?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to nodejs and javascript. I am learning async programming. I am trying to find ip address for a domain name. I am using nodejs inbuild "DNS" library.

```
dns.resolve(domainName, function onLookup(err, addresses, family) {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                 console.log(addresses);
                 var domainAddress = addresses;
            }
        });
```

This is the actual code. I am trying to get the domainAddress out of the call back. Since its async programming, it takes time to get the domainAddress and i am unable to access it for some time.

If i am using a code something like this, i am able to access the domainAddress

```
dns.resolve(domainName, function onLookup(err, addresses, family) {
                                if (err){
                                    res.send(err);
                                } else {
                                    domainAddress = addresses;
                                }
                            });

        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(domainAddress);
        }, 1000);
```

But this i do not feel this is the right way to export a result from callback to the main program.

Can you please give any alternate solution for this problem ?

NOTE: 
I want to do additional task once i get the IP. I want to find the geo location based on the ip address. For that i need to pass this IP to a separate module called Geoip-lite. But since i am unable to get the address outside its getting very difficult

Comment: You can't all the operations that depends on `domainAddress` should be placed within the callback

Comment: Don't use setTimeout, you don't know how many time is necessary...

Comment: Wrap you dns.resolve call in a function with a callback as parameter. Call that callback with the domainAdress

Comment: just look inside a function that uses callbacks and you might understand the concept more clearly

Comment: @CViejo - can you please provide an example.

Comment: @Bala take a look at BlackMamba's answer below. It's doing exactly that

Comment: I want to do additional task once i get the IP. I want to find the geo location based on the ip address. For that i need to pass this IP to a separate module called Geoip-lite. But since i am unable to get the address outside its getting very difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myResolve(domainName, callback){
    dns.resolve(domainName, function onLookup(err, addresses, family) {
            if (err){
                return callback(err);
            } else {
                return callback(null, addresses);
            }
        });
}


myResolve(domainName, function(err, addresses){
    if(err){
        return res.send(err);
    } else {
        return res.send(addresses);
    }
});
```

Please try this code.

Comment: Could you explain what you've done? It's clearer if there is an explanation.

Comment: Don't rush too much to give answers. The `setTimeout` can be removed here.

Comment: This code is not working. I do not want to send the response after this function. I want to do more after getting the ip address. So i want to export the address to the main function.

Comment: Now i understand how this works. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

try node.js async module.
you can use async series for this.

```
 var domainAddress;
function findDNS(callback){
   dns.resolve(domainName, function onLookup(err, addresses, family) {
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        } else {
             console.log(addresses);
              domainAddress = addresses;
              callback(null,"Address found")    
        }
    });
}
function doWhatever(callback){
   console.log("DNS:"+domainAddress);
   callback(null,"OK");
}
async.series([findDNS,doWhatever],function (err, results){
    console.log(results);

});
```

Comment: async series works and i think i can chain all my events  to the array.

Comment: you can add more events in this array